# Making list out of an iterator produces unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Can anyone please explain why iterating over a list that is produced from iterator X is producing a different result compared to iterating over iterator X?

In other words [x for x in list(IteratorObject)] != [x for x in IteratorObject]

```
>>> randoms = [random.randrange(10) for i in range(100)]

>>> [ (x[0],list(x[1])) for x in itertools.groupby(sorted(randoms))]
[(0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), (1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), (2, [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), (3, [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]), (4, [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]), (5, [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]), (6, [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]), (7, [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]), (8, [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]), (9, [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9])]

>>> [ (x[0],list(x[1])) for x in list(itertools.groupby(sorted(randoms)))]
[(0, []), (1, []), (2, []), (3, []), (4, []), (5, []), (6, []), (7, []), (8, []), (9, [9])]

>>> sys.version
'3.3.3 (default, Dec  2 2013, 01:40:21) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)]'
```

Comment: what is ur expected output

Comment: Could you provide your assignment to `randoms`, just for the sake of clarity?

Comment: First result is an expected one.
I've added a string explaining what randoms is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterators that are yielded for each group from `itertools.groupby` are not independent of the top-level iteration. You need to consume each one of them before you go on to the next group, or the iterator becomes invalid (it will yield nothing further).

This behavior is referenced in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list

Your two list comprehensions show this. In the first one, you call `list` on `x[1]`, which is the iterator. In the second version, all of the iterators are produced first in the `list` call around the `groupby` call, and only when you iterate over that list do the inner iterators get consumed. Note that the iterator over last group (`[9]`) does work!

Here's a simpler example:

```
groupby_iter = itertools.groupby([1,1,2,2])
first_val, first_group = next(groupby_iter)

# right now, we can iterate on `first_group`:
print(next(first_group)) # prints 1

# but if we advance groupby_iter to the next group...
second_val, second_group = next(groupby_iter)

# first_group is now invalid (it won't yield the second 1)
print(next(first_group)) # raises StopIteration
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this point in the documentation explains the problem:

"The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list"

In your second example, when you convert to a list, you immediately iterate through all of the groups.  But within each group, you don't iterate through the underlying elements.  When you finally try to do that with list(x[1]), it's too late - you've already exhausted the iterator.